# cannot view post request image in console

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, server

i have a canvas where is stream video, i'm taking a snapshot of that and sending it to a server how do i know that i have sent the snapshot successfully to server ? i cant see anything in 'Preview' section and should my payload look like that ?. I can see the snapshot in front end using that img tag.
status is :

[image]

and in payload getting:

[image]

and there is nothing in 'Preview'

[image]

```js
const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState('');

  const getImage = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>
      canvasRef?.current.toBlob((blob) => {
        const src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        setPreview(src);
        resolve(blob);
      }),
    );
  };
 
 
 const takeSnapshott = async () => {
    let pollUrl = `api/cam/${first}/${second}/snap`;
   
    const blob = await getImage();
    // SEND THE BLOB TO YOUR SERVER
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', blob, 'picture');
    try {
      const res = await fetch(pollUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        body: formData,
      });
      const data = await res.text();
      console.log('resso', data);

      if (res.ok) console.log('SUCCESS', data);
      else throw new Error(data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
```

```html
          <img src={preview} style={{ width: '100%', height: 'auto' }} />
```

Comment: The "Preview" section is for the _response_ and not the request. It is surprisingly hard to extract the file upload in the request from devtools. It would probably be easier to use a tool like Fiddler.

Comment: So this blob image has been sent to server ? And if ’Preview’ section is for response then what is that ’Response’ section which is next to ’Preview’

Comment: It's the raw response. "Preview" is to show things such as a rendered version of HTML returned in the response.